# Why would .NET OpenXML SDK's SpreadsheetDocument.Open() method throw a NullReferenceException?

Tags: c#, .net, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm absolutely stumped by this, and could find nothing all morning searching Google.

I have a method that looks more or less like this:

```
public void Open(string fileName, bool isEditable)
{
    if(this.Document != null) this.Document.Close();
    this.Document = SpreadSheetDocument.Open(fileName, isEditable);
}
```

It's only slightly more complex than that (for example, a provision to use a previously set filename if the arg is null or ZLS), but nothing relevant to the issue here.

When I run this code I get a NullReferenceException on the last line of the method there.  Per the MSDN documentation, the only exceptions this method should throw are ArgumentNullException or OpenXMLPackageException.  The file is not open in any other application, I've tried moving it to various locations, in case it was a permissions issue, and it is most definitely a well-formed .xslx file, created and saved in Excel.

In case it wasn't obvious, this is part of a helper-class I've written to reduce the workload involved in opening spreadsheets and extracting the data, mostly used for when it isn't as simple as importing into Access.  'this.Document' is a property of type SpreadsheetDocument.  Here's the exception detail:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source=DocumentFormat.OpenXml
StackTrace:
   at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPackage.get_FileOpenAccess()
   at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPackage.SavePartContents()
   at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPackage.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPackage.Dispose()
   at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPackage.Close()
   at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPackage.Load()
   at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPackage.OpenCore(String path, Boolean readWriteMode)
   at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.SpreadsheetDocument.Open(String path, Boolean isEditable, OpenSettings openSettings)
   at DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.SpreadsheetDocument.Open(String path, Boolean isEditable)
   at CorbLib.OXML.Spreadsheets.XLDoc.Open(String fileName, Boolean isEditable) in C:\[path removed]\XLDoc.cs:line 37
   at CorbLib.OXML.Spreadsheets.XLDoc.GetCell(String sheetName, String cellRef) in C:\[path removed]\XLDoc.cs:line 48
   at CorbLib.OXML.Spreadsheets.XLDoc.GetCellsFromRange(String range, Boolean leaveOpen) in C:\[path removed]\XLDoc.cs:line 139
   at CorbLib.OXML.Spreadsheets.XLDoc.GetCellValues(String range, Boolean leaveOpen) in C:\[path removed]\XLDoc.cs:line 116
   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\[path removed]\Program.cs:line 14
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
InnerException:
```

Any assistance wold be tremendously helpful.

**EDIT:** As per the comments in the accepted answer, I have modified the above method as follows...

```
public void Open(string fileName, bool isEditable)
{
    /*unimportant bits*/
    var fs = new FileStream(this.FullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    this.Document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fs, this.IsEditable);
}
```

...and it now works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's a bug in the DocumentFormat.OpenXml library. Inside the Load function there is a catch block, as first thing it calls the Close method:

```
try
{
    // Some stuff
}
catch (OpenXMLPackageException)
{
    Close();
    throw;
}
```

When an exception is caught the `Close()` method is invoked but if it happens **before** it's fully initialized and the Close method itself throws the NullReferenceException, hiding the original one.

You may see what's wrong inside the output window of Visual Studio. You should be able to catch the right error attaching in debug with Visual Studio (at least you'll read the original exception message).

Comment: I wish it was that simple.  This is all that prints when I step into that last line:
    Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'CorbLib.OXML.Spreadsheets.XLDoc.FullPath.get'
    Step into: Stepping over non-user code 'CorbLib.OXML.Spreadsheets.XLDoc.IsEditable.get'
    A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll

Comment: I do think that you're correct about the bug, though.  I just tried it with the (Stream, bool) overload instead and it worked beautifully.  Quite frustrating.  Thanks for the nudge in the right direction!